# Why Satyanarayan Puja is preferred for griha pravesh (house warming ceremony)?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, rituals, resource, satyanarayana

In griha pravesh(house warming ceremony) for new house I always heard about doing a Satyanarayana Puja. But why? Why only Satyanarayan Puja and is there any significance over any other type of puja? Is it mentioned in any scripture that we should do Satyanarayana Puja for griha pravesh? Is there any story behind it?

Comment: It is just a regional custom not mandatory. There is no such actual tradition.

Comment: Can you tell us the regions where it follows @Rakesh Joshi !

Comment: @SantanuDebnath Mainly in Andhra, TN, Karnataka, Gujarat, Rajasthan.

Comment: In a warm country like India, the translation of Griha-pravesha can not be house warming!!

Answer (score 2):

**Satyanarayan Puja**

> The Satyanarayan Puja is a religious worship of the Hindu god Vishnu.
>   Satya means “truth” and narayana means, “The highest being” so
>   Satyanarayan means “The highest being who is an embodiment of
>   Truth”.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyanarayan_Puja) Vrat or Puja means a religious vow, religious
>   observance, or obligation. Hindus throughout [3] perform Sri
>   Satyanarayan Vrat for the divine blessings of health, wealth,
>   prosperity, opulence, education; relief from troubles and sickness. It
>   can also be performed because of success in business or career growth;
>   during social functions like marriages, house-warming ceremonies,
>   naming of the children and so on.

**The Satyanarayan Katha – Story Behind the Ritual**

> The puja is performed from the Skanda Purana. The story is narrated by
>   Sutha Puranik, a rishi, who is narrating the story to a group of
>   rishis performing a thousand year yajna for the benefit of mankind.
>   The rishis asked Sutha Pramanik as to how an individual with ethical
>   and life-affirming desires could have his desires fulfilled.
>
> Sutha further explained that this same question was also asked by
>   Narada, another great rishi and the son of Lord Bramha or the creator.
>   Narada is one famous character that pops up all through Vedic
>   mythology as an instigator who could set everything in motion. He had
>   the finest comic sense and mischief.
>
> In this tale, Narada is shown travelling the entire universe before
>   coming to the Earth, or Bhuloka. On earth, he found that many people
>   have been suffering as they were living through their karma from the
>   past life. That filled him with compassion for the ones suffering and
>   he went to Lord Vishnu and asked if something could be done to help
>   these people.
>
> Narada and Lord Vishnu were great friends. Vishnu, in turn, asked
>   Narada for suggestion. Narada then explained that there’s a puja that
>   can be performed by everyone to eliminate sufferings from their life;
>   it is called the Satyanarayan puja. He also added that this puja can
>   be done by everyone; it is not necessary to have a priest, at any time
>   without having to wait for an auspicious moment. Apart from this,
>   there are other stories as a part of the Satyanarayan Katha, which
>   makes this ritual a celebration.

References: [here](http://www.satyanarayanpuja.org/shri-satyanarayan-katha.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyanarayan_Puja)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to understand the name on a deeper level, you can precisely understand that Satya means Truth and Narayan means more like abiding in everybody and everything. Therefore, the praise of Lord Satyanarayana implies that in order to overcome any obstacles caused in life, one must need to worship the Truth. In other words, a human has to be oneself and then be truthful to others. The more authentic you are, the more you can see the Narayan in others.

Once upon a time, there lived an old and poor Brahman in Kashi. He was poor and used to beg to as his source of income. Now, Narada loves Brahmans and hence obscured by the fate of this Brahman.

Thus, he straight away headed to the Brahman and asked him, what could free you? The Brahman further elaborated that, “I am basically old and poor. So, I want a way to free from poverty.” Upon hearing his afflict, the Narada headed to the Lord Vishnu and asked for a solution. Something that could erase the miseries of humans on this planet.

In response, the Lord himself stated that worshipping Lord Satyanarayana will lead him to the ultimate way of happiness. The Brahman did that and certainly freed from poverty. This has been spread across the nation and people gradually adopted it.

It is also common belief amongst Hindus that we should focus on universal happiness and unity.

Reference: [Here](https://www.subhayogam.com/blog/what-is-the-significance-of-the-satyanarayan-puja) & [Here](http://www.satyanarayanpuja.org/significance-of-satyanarayan-puja.html)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, as per our scriptures, every work should be done after worshipping Narayana, Who is the Abode of all goods, the most adorable and giver of all good boons

> sarva-mangala-mangalyam varenyam varadam shuvam/ nArAyanam namaskritya sarvakarmAni kArayet//

To worship Narayana, Satyanarayana-Puja is known to be the most fruitful in the kali-yuga according to the Reva-khanda of the Skanda-Purana:

> dhana-dhAnyAdikam gasya bhabet Satya-prasAdatah/..visheshatah kaliyuge satyapujA mahAfalA//
>
> Meaning : By the grace of Lord Satya-NArAyana, people get all types of fulfillment like wealth, food etc.Especially in the Kaliyuga, the worship of Satya-NArAyana yields great fruits.

I think these answer the question.